# Django redirect to DetailView From FormView

Tags: django-forms, django-class-based-views

What I'm trying to do is to have a form with a single field that gets a primary key and redirects to DetailView of that primary key. While I can achieve this by having a ListView and then go to the DetailView from ListView that's an extra step I don't need as I already have a primary key. Any help would be appreciated.

models.py

```
class Book(models.model):
    book_id = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
    # some other fields
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('book-detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

forms.py

```
class BookSearchForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['book_id']
```

views.py

```
class BookDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Book
    template_name = 'book-detail.html'
```

with a ListView I can do it like below:

```
class BookListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'book-list.html'
    form_class = BookSearchForm

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        book_id = self.request.Get.get('book_id', None)
        if book_id:
            qs=qs.filter(book_id=book_id).first()
        if not book_id:
            qs=qs.none()
        return qs
```

How can I do it without a ListView??

```
class BookSearchView(FormView):
    template_name = 'book-search.html'
    form_class = BookSearchForm
    # what should I do here, form_valid, get?
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('book/search/',BookSearchView.as_view(),name='book-search'),
    path('book/<str:pk>/',BookDetailView.as_view(),name='book-detail')
]
```

book-search.html

```
<form action="." method="GET">
    {{form}}
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well to redirect to the DetailView you can specify a success url in your FormView like so:

```
class BookSearchView(FormView):
    template_name = 'book-search.html'
    form_class = BookSearchForm
    success_url = '' # The url that you want to direct after form is validated 
    
     def form_valid(self, form):
        # This method is called when valid form data has been POSTed.
        # It should return an HttpResponse.
        
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Thanks but this didn't solve the problem. I've tried the self.book_id = form.cleaned_data['book_id'] in the form_valid and then return reverse('book-detail', kwargs={'book_id':self.book_id}) in the get_success_url but still not working.

Comment: The form method is GET not POST. Let me put it this way. I have a FormView. I want to redirect to a DetailView using the input from users. I have to be able to access the request.GET.get('book_id') in get_success_url

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am mistaken but it would appear to are trying to access the `book_id` from the `BookSearchView` object which does not have that attribute. I think you can access the created object by overriding the `form_valid` like this

```
def form_valid(self, form) -> HttpResponse:
        self.object = form.save()
        .....
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

And then you will have access to the object which you can use to access the `book_id` in the `get_success_url` method like this

```
def get_success_url(self) -> str:
        return reverse_lazy('book-detail', kwargs={'book_id': self.object.book_id})
```

I feel like there is probably a better way of doing it but this is how I got it to work.